# Fonts similar to Ubuntu Condensed?

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

We're experimenting with using [Ubuntu Condensed](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Ubuntu+Condensed) as [our website's](http://goo.gl/k7gCZb) primary font. The non-condensed Ubuntu font has too much width, and feels splayed out. Previously, we were using Signika.

It's sometimes recommended not to use a condensed font as your primary font, so we're considering other comparable options. Can anyone recommend non-condensed fonts with a look that's comparable to Ubuntu, but which are narrower than Ubuntu Regular? Alternatively, is it fine, in terms of legibility and other considerations, to just go with the condensed variant?

Comment: Even though you already know what the font it is, I recommend running a sample of Ubuntu through an identification service such as [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) or [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/). They should give you similar fonts. Let us know what they come up with; if they're not what you're looking for then let us know why

Comment: Great suggestion - thanks. WhatTheFont is coming up with: Robusta Cond Regular, Stainless Comp, Etelka Narrow Text Pro, Formata Pro ExtraCond Regular, and Formata BQ ExtraCond. I'll check out how those look. WhatFontIs doesn't like the samples I'm providing so far, so I'll have to come up with some better ones.

Comment: "Condensed" isn't really a thing in and of itself. It's just a narrower version of whatever is deemed "regular" width. So the recommendation to not use a condensed face is really "do not use a narrow face". While Ubuntu Condensed is narrower than regular, I wouldn't say it's extremely narrow and seems quite legible so I'd stick with that.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Encode Condensed](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/encode-sans?filter%5Bsettings%5D%5B0%5D=show_more_tags&filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=condensed) quite readable. Even though it is condensed too, it is much wider and has more legible forms than Ubuntu condensed.